# User Defined Function that returns the values of a single column concatenated together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and would like to have a user defined function that concatenates the values of a single column, comma delimited, and returns it.

For example, a table with the following rows:

```
column1
---------
head
shoulders
knees
toes
```

The function would return the single value: `head, shoulders, knees, toes`

Comment: If you know how to write a UDF, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string should be all you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDF version of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetNumDaysInMonth] ()
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000) 
   SELECT @str= COALESCE(@str + ', ', '') + column_name FROM tablename ORDER BY column_name
   return @str
END
```